# C# NullReferenceException in class validation method

Tags: c#, class, validation

I am trying to add a helper method to scrub out any non-alphanumeric characters in my class. However, I keep getting the error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here since I thought this was the proper way to set up any kind of validation within a class. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    private string agentId;
    public string AgentId
    {
        get { return agentId; }
        set { agentId = this.scrubAgentId(); } 
    }

    private string scrubAgentId()
    {
        char[] arr = this.AgentId.ToCharArray();

        arr = Array.FindAll<char>(arr, (c => (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))));
        return new string(arr);
    }
```

Comment: AgentId is null in scrubAgentId's `char[] arr = this.AgentId.ToCharArray();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really right at all. You're discarding the `value` when performing your set. It should probably look something more like this:

```
    private string agentId;
    public string AgentId
    {
        get { return agentId; }
        set { agentId = this.scrubAgentId(value); } 
    }

    private string scrubAgentId(string value)
    {
        if(value == null)
            return value;
        char[] arr = value.ToCharArray();

        arr = Array.FindAll<char>(arr, (c => (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))));
        return new string(arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `set` part of the property you have an implicit object, `value` which holds the value you want to set... Use this value as your base

```
private string agentId;
public string AgentId
{
    get { return agentId; }
    set { agentId = value; } // manipulate value here using your method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you initialising agentid anywhere first?

Its failing on `char[] arr = this.AgentId.ToCharArray();`

Answer (score 0):

You never reference the `value` in your setter. You want to do something like this:

```
private string agentId;
public string AgentId
{
    get
    {
      return agentId ;
    }
    set
    {
      agentId = new string( value.ToCharArray().Where( c => c.IsLetterOrDigit(c) ) ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if a caller attempts to set `AgentId=null;`

Comment: Obviously. You might notice the 'something like this' qualification. How to handle the edge case there should be pretty obvious (and dependent on the desired semantics of the property).